# Verificar data e hora do arquivo e manter o mais atual em Batch

Tags: batch, comparação

Preciso de um programa em Batch onde irei especificar dois arquivos, ele irá comparar a data e hora da criação dos mesmos e caso o primeiro seja mais atual ele deletaria o segundo e copiaria o primeiro, caso o contrário ele não irá fazer nada.

Comment: Quando você diz "batch", se refere a um programa que possa ser agendado escrito em qualquer linguagem ou um programa usando Spring Batch?

Comment: Olá @GiulianaBezerra

Preciso que esse programa seja em .bat (arquivos de lote) ou em VBA, eu irei agendar esse programa no Task Scheduler do Windows para rodar a cada 30min, verificando se alguém fez novas atualizações no programa da empresa, essa verificação será feita comparando a data e a hora de modificação do arquivo, caso tenho alguma alteração ele irá deletar o arquivo antigo e fazer a copia do arquivo novo.

Comment: O arquivo é muito grande? Porque não vejo a necessidade da comparação, sobrescreve ele é pronto, rsrs

Comment: @AlexandreUeda, esses arquivos estarão numa só pasta? Você pode usar essa resposta que coloquei, vou adicionar um comando para que copie o conteúdo de uma pasta caso o arquivo seja mais recente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse comando não deleta, mas só copia e sobrescreve se o arquivo de origem for mais novo do que o de destino.

Deve colocar o caminho completo dos arquivos para que funcione corretamente.

A cópia faz com que o arquivo de destino seja substituído pelo de origem, se o nome do arquivo for diferente e o arquivo de origem for mais recente, a cópia será realizada, mas o nome continuará o do arquivo de destino.

```
@echo off

set /p file1=Digite o caminho e nome do arquivo 1: 

set /p file2=Digite o caminho e nome do arquivo 2: 

xcopy "%file1%" "%file2%" /y /d

pause
```

Caso queira copiar somente os arquivos mais recentes de uma determinada pasta basta fazer conforme abaixo:

```
xcopy "C:\PastaOrigem\." "C:\PastaDestino" /y /d
```

Entenda mais sobre o xcopy:

```
Copia arquivos e árvores de diretórios.

XCOPY origem [destino] [/A | /M] [/D[:data]] [/P] [/S [/E]] [/V] [/W]
                           [/C] [/I] [/Q] [/F] [/L] [/G] [/H] [/R] [/T] [/U]
                           [/K] [/N] [/O] [/X] [/Y] [/-Y] [/Z] [/B] [/J]
                          [/EXCLUDE:arquivo1[+arquivo2][+arquivo3]...]

  origem       Especifica o(s) arquivo(s) a ser(em) copiado(s).
  destino  Especifica o local e/ou o nome dos novos arquivos.
  /A           Copia somente arquivos com o atributo de arquivamento
               definido; nao altera o atributo.
  /M           Copia somente arquivos com o atributo de arquivamento
               definido; desativa o atributo de arquivamento.
  /D:m-d-a     Copia os arquivos alterados durante ou após a data
               especificada. Se nao for definida uma data, copia apenas os
               arquivos cujo tempo de origem seja mais novo do que o tempo
               de destino.
  /EXCLUDE:arquivo1[+arquivo2][+arquivo3]...
               Especifica uma lista de arquivos contendo cadeias de
               caracteres. Cada cadeia deve estar em uma linha separada nos
               arquivos. Quando qualquer cadeia corresponder a qualquer parte
               do caminho absoluto do arquivo a ser copiado, esse arquivo
               deixará de ser copiado. Por exemplo, especificar uma cadeia de
               caracteres como \obj\ ou .obj excluirá todos os arquivos sob o
               diretório obj ou com a extensao .obj, respectivamente.
  /P           Solicita confirmaçao antes de criar cada arquivo de destino.
  /S           Copia diretórios e subdiretórios, exceto os vazios.
  /E           Copia diretórios e subdiretórios, inclusive os vazios.
               O mesmo que /S /E. Pode ser usado para modificar /T.
  /V           Verifica o tamanho de cada novo arquivo.
  /W           Solicita que você pressione uma tecla antes de copiar.
  /C           Continua copiando, mesmo que ocorram erros.
  /I           Se o destino nao existir e mais de um arquivo estiver sendo
               copiado, pressupoe que o destino deve ser um diretório.
  /Q           Nao exibe os nomes de arquivos ao copiar.
  /F           Exibe os nomes de arquivos de origem e de destino completos ao
               copiar.
  /L           Exibe arquivos que seriam copiados.
  /G           Permite a cópia de arquivos criptografados para um destino que
               nao oferece suporte a criptografia.
  /H           Copia arquivos ocultos e do sistema também.
  /R           Substitui arquivos somente leitura.
  /T           Cria a estrutura de diretórios, mas nao copia arquivos. Nao
               inclui diretórios ou subdiretórios vazios. /T /E inclui
               diretórios e subdiretórios vazios.
  /U           Copia apenas os arquivos que já existem no destino.
  /K           Copia atributos. O Xcopy normal redefinirá os atributos
               somente leitura.
  /N           Copia usando os nomes curtos gerados.
  /O           Copia as informaçoes de ACL e proprietário do arquivo.
  /X           Copia configuraçoes de auditoria de arquivo (implica /O).
  /Y           Suprime o prompt para você confirmar se deseja substituir
               um arquivo de destino existente.
  /-Y          Exibe o prompt para você confirmar se deseja substituir
               um arquivo de destino existente.
  /Z           Copia arquivos de rede no modo reiniciável.
  /B           Copia o próprio Vínculo Simbólico, e nao o destino do vínculo.
  /J           Copia usando E/S sem buffer. Recomendável para arquivos muito
               grandes.

A opçao /Y pode ser predefinida na variável de ambiente COPYCMD.
Isso pode ser anulado por /-Y na linha de comando.
```